# firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser return null at the first call

Tags: android, mvvm, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement login activity with Firebase under MVVM model. I use Firebase login with Email and Password to check whether or not a user exits in the database.

However, the method getCurrentUser always returns NULL at the first call. Meaning, when I type in the correct user name and password (which exists in the database) and click on Login button, the result that I get is NULL. But when I click on the second time, it will return the correct user ID. Please help me fix on this one. Thank you so much.

This is my codes

MainAcitivy:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mUserName = findViewById(R.id.txt_userName);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
    mBtnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    mMainActivityViewModels = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModels.class);
    mMainActivityViewModels.init();

    mBtnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            appLogin(mUserName.getText().toString(), mPassword.getText().toString());}
```

```
private void appLogin(String userName, String password){
        String userID;
        if(userName.length() == 0 && password.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User name and Password are incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            userID = mMainActivityViewModels.signIn(this, userName, password).getValue();
            if(userID == null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User name and Password are incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                homeIntent.putExtra("userID", userID);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
            }
}
```

MainActivityViewModels:

```
public class MainActivityViewModels extends ViewModel {
private MainActivityRepository mMainActivityRepo;

public void init(){
    mMainActivityRepo = MainActivityRepository.getInstance();
}

public LiveData<String> signIn(Activity activity, String user_name, String pass){
    return mMainActivityRepo.signInWithEmailAndPassword(activity, user_name, pass);


}
```

MainActivityRepository:

```
public class MainActivityRepository {
private static MainActivityRepository instance;
private static MutableLiveData<String> userID;
private static FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

public static MainActivityRepository getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new MainActivityRepository();
    }

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    return instance;
}

public MutableLiveData<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(Activity activity, String userName, String password){
    public MutableLiveData<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(Activity activity, String userName, String password){
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userName, password).addOnCompleteListener(activity,
            new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(); 
                        userID.setValue(user.getUid());

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Unsuccessful login");
                    }

                }
            }
    );
    return userID;

}
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.snote, PID: 31470
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.getValue()' on a null object reference
    at com.snote.MainActivity.appLogin(MainActivity.java:34)
    at com.snote.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:21)
    at com.snote.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:89)
```

===========================================================================
**Solution**:

I figured out a solution for this:

I will add the AuthStateListener inside onStart method and make sure that user will logout onStop method:

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    firebaseAuth.signOut();

}

@Override
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
        homeIntent.putExtra("UID", userID);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
}
```

Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bug in the SDK.  I suggest [filing it on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk).

What you can do instead is use the [AuthResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult) delivered to the onComplete callback, which should contain the current user object.

```
FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this way, but I still get the same issue.

Comment: Then I suggest filing a bug with your steps to reproduce.